# How can I use current site cookies to login to another site and then redirect to another page and make a CURL request?

Tags: php, curl, cookies

How can I use current site cookies to login to another site and then redirect to another page ?

I have multiple websites which uses the same external Authenticator.I am trying to make a CURL request from one site to get data from the other site . But I have authentication issue while making the CURL request to other site.

In order to login to another site I need to click on login URL but credentials need not be entered again.

So My actual requirement is :

1. Use Cookies from current site.
2. Make a CURL request to another site login URL and login to that site using Cookies from current site.
3. Make a CURL request to another URL where you can obtain the required data.

I can obtain data from the other site if I am logged into that site in the browser.

My Current Code is as follows:

```
$agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)";
$loginURL = $url . 'saml_login';
$cleanedURL = $url . 'anotherurl/list';

$curl = curl_init();

//Before making CURl request to $cleanedURL I need to make request to $loginURL(which has a redirect)

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $cleanedURL);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Cookie: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump($response);
```

All the examples I came across used either used credentials in the header or cookies file which is already exported.

Can any one help me to suggest it.

Comment: When I click on Login it makes a post request  to SSO and logins to another site.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie sharing is possible by domain. If your application at app.domain.com register a cookie for wildcard domain.com instead of app.domain.com, any subdomain.domain.com will have the access to the cookie key.

Comment: Actually my websites uses the domains in the following manner
https://example.com/site1/ , 
https://example.com/site2/ , 
https://example.com/site3/

Comment: You can make a test, write a cookie on site1, and make a console.log of the cookie key via javascript on site2 and site3. Cookies are managed by browser and webserver using the domain to know whom can use them.

Comment: You can also follow some examples like if you have a subapp for login to generate a token like auth.yourdomain.com, this subapp can register the token in a cookie for the wildcard of domain that should be yourdomain.com and any subapp.yourdomain.com will be able to use. It also should works with subpath once the domain keep the same like yourdomain.com/app.

Comment: Actually the problem is websites are using cookies from other sites , but only in the case when I click on login page. So the problem is how I curl login page first and later another curl to some other page.

Comment: You will need to curl the login website, store the cookie result and curl to another one passing these cookies in the http header. There is no another way to do what you're trying to do.